# How unique must a key/id be in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-key-index

So, i usually make super-duper unique ids and keys for components that need it. But I wonder, how unique do they need to be? If they don't live in the same parent, is it important that they are different?

Please share you experience and thoughts :)

Comment: keys must be unique within same parent.

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn't matter.
I've done performance tests on it.
The fact that it is in a **unique** div other than the component you gave the **key** is enough to distinguish it for the DOM.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).